# FileReader IE9 gera erro

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema ao instanciar o FileReader no IE9 gera erro pesquisei e vi que o IE9 não funciona pois não suporta HTML 5 alguém tem uma outra solução?

Comment: Há um projeto que simula essa funcionalidade aqui: https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader

Comment: Então IE9 não suporta preciso de uma outra solução.

Comment: Não duplique perguntas, já esta bem claro que duplicar não ajuda a conseguir respostas mais rapidas e só prejudica o resto da comunidade, imagina se todo mundo que não conseguir respostas comece a duplicar, vai ser uma festa de perguntas repetidas. Entenda como uma critica construtiva, a outra já tem respostas vou fechar esta.